# Cannot follow steps provided in trailhead, trying to deploy Loyalty data bundle in vanilla trial data cloud org: LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger

Tags: datacloud, loyalty-management

I am trying to follow this trailhead module
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/loyalty-management-and-cdp-integration/set-up-the-org?assignmentId=a5c3m0000023kvqAAA
and I am trying to select  the Loyalty data bundle, however, I receive an error

```
Insufficient Permissions
{iconAlternativeText)
You do not have permission to import records for 1 object. Please check with your Salesforce Admin to make the following object available for use.Tell Me More
LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger
Object unavailable
```

[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I tried to add every single Loyalty object to the permission set, but it still doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

I don't have any customization, I just requested a vanilla Data Cloud trial org... I struggle to find the label for the LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger object, based on the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/sforce_api_objects_loyaltyaggrpointexprledger.htm LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger isn't available in the Object Manager and can't be customized.

If this object can't be granted permissions to, how am I supposed to grant access to this object?

---

Even if I try to add permission by code

```
    insert new ObjectPermissions(
        ParentId = '0PSHn000000eA1n', 
        SobjectType = 'LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger',
        PermissionsCreate = true,
        PermissionsDelete = true,
        PermissionsEdit = true,
        PermissionsModifyAllRecords = true,
        PermissionsRead = true,
        PermissionsViewAllRecords = true
    );
```

it fails with an error:

```
Line: 1, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid object: LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger: []
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Opened a Salesforce case about this.

Salesforce support suggested to apply the steps in the following article:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.loyalty_points_consolidation_real_time.htm&type=5

The settings under 'Consolidate Member Points for Expiration' section in Loyalty Management setup Settings should enable the LoyaltyAggrPointExprLedger object for the org.

[image]

If I enable `Consolidate members’ fixed non-qualifying points in real time.` setting under Loyalty Management Settings, object Loyalty Aggregated Point Expiration Ledger appear and becomes available for permission setting.
[image]
When now I add this object, the error is gone and I can deploy loyalty stream.